# Probability tricky exercise

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I was given this exercise:

> The manager of a company has 2 possible designs for his new line of
> artificial brains. The first option has an 80% of probability of
> producing 70% of the artificial brains in good conditions and a 20% of
> probabilities of producing 50% of the artificial brains in good
> conditions, being 450000 dollars the cost of these designs. The second
> option has a 70% of probability of producing 70% of the artificial
> brains in good conditions and a 30% of probabilities of producing 50%
> of the artificial brains in good conditions, being 600000 dollars the
> cost of this design. The cost of each artifical brain is 100 dollars,
> it if is good its cost is 250 dollars while if it is in bad condition
> it has no price. Knowing that the vision on the compay is to create
> 50000 artificial brains, which design must be chosen by the manager?

I did this but im not sure

```
Option 1:

80% * 70% * 50,000 = 2,800,000 good artificial brains
20% * 50% * 50,000 = 500,000 good artificial brains
Total good artificial brains: 3,300,000
Total cost: $450,000
Total revenue: 3,300,000 * $250 = $825,000,000
Expected profit: $825,000,000 - $450,000 = $824,550,000
Option 2:

70% * 70% * 50,000 = 2,450,000 good artificial brains
30% * 50% * 50,000 = 750,000 good artificial brains
Total good artificial brains: 3,200,000
Total cost: $600,000
Total revenue: 3,200,000 * $250 = $800,000,000
Expected profit: $800,000,000 - $600,000 = $799,400,000

Therefore, based on these calculations, the manager should choose Option 1
```

Is my reasoning okay?

---

```
edit #1

Option 1:

80% * 70% * 50,000 = 2,800,000 good artificial brains
20% * 50% * 50,000 = 500,000 good artificial brains
Total good artificial brains: 3,300,000
Total cost: $450,000
Total revenue: 3,300,000 * $250 = $825,000,000
Expected profit: $825,000,000 - $450,000 = $824,550,000
Option 2:

70% * 70% * 50,000 = 2,450,000 good artificial brains
30% * 50% * 50,000 = 750,000 good artificial brains
Total good artificial brains: 3,200,000
Total cost: $600,000
Total revenue: 3,200,000 * $250 = $800,000,000
Expected profit: $800,000,000 - $600,000 = $799,400,000

Therefore, based on these calculations, the manager should choose option 1
```

Comment: Your basic approach is correct, but you do understand that finding 80% of something does not mean multiply by 80? It cannot have seemed reasonable to you to generate a revenue of \$825,000,000 from a cost of \$450,000.

Comment: Also, what does "The cost of each artifical brain is \$100 dollars, ..." mean? If each brain costs \$100 to make, why is the cost of producing 50,000 brains either \$450,000 or \$600,000? Perhaps those last two numbers are just the cost of the **designs**, and you still have to add in the cost of each brain? E.g. for case 1, the total cost would be \$450,000 + 50,000 (\$100) = \$5,450,000?

Comment: Hey @A.J.  "The cost of each artifical brain is $100 dollars" means the base price

Comment: @A.J. could you help me to solve this? im kinda lost :/

Comment: @A.J. take a look, i have updated my answer

Comment: What did you change? I see no difference at all between the edit #1 and the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure how to reconcile the "cost of each artificial brain is 100 dollars" with the rest of the information given, but in the absence of a better explanation I'm going to assume that the cost of **designing** the two brains is \$450,000 and \$600,000 respectively, while the cost of **manufacturing** the brains is \$100 apiece.

You must be aware that $80\% = \frac{80}{100} = 0.8 \neq 80$; to calculate $80\%$ of $70\%$ of $50,000$, the multiplication would be $(0.8)(0.7)(50,000) = 28,000$. So your option 1 calculations should be as follows:

- $80\%$ of $70\%$ of $50,000 = (0.8)(0.7)(50,000) = 28,000$ good artificial brains
- $20\%$ of $50\%$ of $50,000 = (0.2)(0.5)(50,000) = 5,000$ good artificial brains
- Total good artificial brains: $33,000$
- Total cost: $\$450,000 + 33,000 (\$100) = \$3,750,000$
- Total revenue: $33,000 (\$250) = \$8,250,000$
- Expected profit: $\$8,250,000 - \$3,750,000 = \$4,500,000$

The option 2 calculations should be similar.

Comment: Thank you for replying!.
Yeah, i was a little confused.. thanks for clearing my mind up :)